# How to replace missing values in data?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, missing-data, data-cleaning

[image]

The above picture is part of the data that I'm currently working on and some of the data from fips column are missing. I am trying to replace the missing values using the information from other columns. I want to write a code where if fips value is missing then it will try to match the county and state details with other rows and if there is a match then use the fips code from that row to fill the missing value. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?
`df.groupby(['state', 'county'])['fips'].apply(lambda x : x.bfill().ffill()))`

I am assuming the fips value for each state + county is unique

Comment: It replaced the missing value but some of it was incorrect because it filled value from its previous or next row without matching the state and county. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you tell me if this return any data? `df.groupby(['state', 'county'])['fips'].filter(lambda x: (x.nunique() > 1).any())`
Please also make sure the datatype of fips is float, `df['fips'] = pd.to_numeric(df['fips'])`

Comment: the datatype of fips is float. The mentioned code didn't return any value. It shows AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'.

Comment: It still shows error. (TypeError: 'numpy.bool_' object is not iterable) One pair of state and county has a unique value. For example, all Snohomish + Washington has fips code 53061 while Spokane + Washington has 53063 and so on.

Comment: If it is unique then after you do the `df.groupby(['state', 'county'])` each group of state and county will only have single value. All the code is doing is filling that value for na's,  Can you post the result where you got incorrect values please?. Maybe posting sample data of the instances/groups that you believe the results are not correct will be more helpful to troubleshoot. Also what version of pandas are you using?